# CSS hover effect for multiple DIV s not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, hover, hide

I'm trying to hide multiple `<div>` elements and when someone hover on a `<li>` item respective `<div>` to be display. So I have used a boostrap container and then had a row inside it and then row divided into `<div class="col-2">` and `<div class="col-10>` where all `<li>` items to be in `<div class="col-2">` and hidden `<div>`s to be `<dic class="col-10">`. So this is my code

```css
 #divli01,#divli02,#divli03,#divli04,#divli05{
            display: none;
        }
        #li01:hover +#divli01{
            color: red;
            display: block;
        }
        #li02:hover +#divli02{
            color: red;
            display: block;
        }
        #li03:hover +#divli03{
            color: red;
            display: block;
        }
        #li04:hover +#divli04{
            color: red;
            display: block;
        }
        #li05:hover +#divli05{
            color: red;
            display: block;
        }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-2">
    <ul>
        <li id="li01">A</li>
        <li id="li02">B</li>
        <li id="li03">C</li>
        <li id="li04">D</li>
        <li id="li05">E</li>
        
    </ul>
    
    </div>
    <div class="col-10">
        
    <div id="divli01">
       <p> A section goes here</p>
         <p> A section goes here</p>
         <p> A section goes here</p>
         <p> A section goes here</p>
    </div>
    
    <div id="divli02">
       <p> B section goes here</p>
         <p> B section goes here</p>
         <p> B section goes here</p>
         <p> B section goes here</p>
    </div>
    
    <div id="divli03">
       <p> C section goes here</p>
        <p> C section goes here</p>
        <p> C section goes here</p>
        <p> C section goes here</p>
    </div>
    
    <div id="divli04">
       <p> D section goes here</p>
        <p> D section goes here</p>
        <p> D section goes here</p>
        <p> D section goes here</p>
    </div>
       <div id="divli05">
       <p> E section goes here</p>
        <p> E section goes here</p>
        <p> E section goes here</p>
        <p> E section goes here</p>
    </div>
    
    </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Initially  I have hide all the `<div>` with css `display:none` and then Iam trying to show each div when user hover on a  `<li>` item. But I think I have missed something. So could anyone please help on this.

Comment: From your HTML structure, I do not think it is possible to do that without JavaScript, because you cannot properly select the `div` elements. `+` is adjacent sibling selector, which will not work here.

Comment: @njras if possible could you please submit sample code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have added a class to `ul` element to select li elements easily, you can choose any other method as well.

```js
let li = document.querySelectorAll('.unhover li');

function displayDiv(event) {
  // console.log(event.target.id);
  document.getElementById('div' + event.target.id).style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('div' + event.target.id).style.color = 'red';
}

function hideDiv(event) {
  // console.log(event.target.id);
  document.getElementById('div' + event.target.id).style.display = 'none';

}

li.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('mouseenter', displayDiv);
  item.addEventListener('mouseleave', hideDiv);
});
```

```css
#divli01,
#divli02,
#divli03,
#divli04,
#divli05 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-2">
      <ul class="unhover">
        <li id="li01">A</li>
        <li id="li02">B</li>
        <li id="li03">C</li>
        <li id="li04">D</li>
        <li id="li05">E</li>

      </ul>

    </div>
    <div class="col-10" id="divs">

      <div id="divli01">
        <p> A section goes here</p>
        <p> A section goes here</p>
        <p> A section goes here</p>
        <p> A section goes here</p>
      </div>

      <div id="divli02">
        <p> B section goes here</p>
        <p> B section goes here</p>
        <p> B section goes here</p>
        <p> B section goes here</p>
      </div>

      <div id="divli03">
        <p> C section goes here</p>
        <p> C section goes here</p>
        <p> C section goes here</p>
        <p> C section goes here</p>
      </div>

      <div id="divli04">
        <p> D section goes here</p>
        <p> D section goes here</p>
        <p> D section goes here</p>
        <p> D section goes here</p>
      </div>
      <div id="divli05">
        <p> E section goes here</p>
        <p> E section goes here</p>
        <p> E section goes here</p>
        <p> E section goes here</p>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use Javascript, then you'll need to change the html structure to be able to use CSS for that task. You can do this by nesting your `col-2` & `col-10` divs inside the `<li>` element. Then using css u can set:

```
li:hover .col-10 {display: block}
```

If you don't want to change html structure, then you'll use Javascript to add event listeners to `<li>` elements ('mouseenter' & 'mouseleave') so that you can add/remove a class to the corresponding div on mouse enter/leave

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this using jQuery.

Here is the link of codepen.
It's something similar that you want...

```
[https://codepen.io/multanisadik/pen/jjvrqq]
```

Please review it. if it's helpful for you.